# Error while running Convolutional Autoencoder RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

Tags: pytorch

I am a noob and am creating a model in PyTorch for the first time. I am trying to create a convolutional autoencoder and am getting the error while running the model. The code I am using is:

```py
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, image_paths, target_paths, train=True):
        self.image_paths = image_paths
        self.target_paths = target_paths

    def transform(self, image, target):
        # Transform to tensor
        resize = transforms.Resize(size=(2350,1650))
        image = resize(image)
        target = resize(target)
        grayscale = transforms.Grayscale(1)
        image = grayscale(image)
        target = grayscale(target)
        image = TF.to_tensor(image)
        target = TF.to_tensor(target)
        return image, target

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        image = Image.open(self.image_paths[index])
        target = Image.open(self.target_paths[index])
        x, y = self.transform(image, target)
        return x, y

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_paths)

traindata = MyDataset(image_paths=train_data, target_paths=target_data, train=True)
testdata = MyDataset(image_paths=test_data, target_paths=None, train=False)

train_loader = DataLoader(traindata, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
test_loader = DataLoader(testdata, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, num_workers=4)

class ConvolutionalAutoEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConvolutionalAutoEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder_block1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 64, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 64, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True)
        )
        self.decoder_block1 = nn.Sequential(   
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 64, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 64, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True)
         )
        self.decoder_block0 = nn.Sequential(  
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 1, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        x1 = self.encoder_block1(x)
        y1 = self.decoder_block1(x1)
        y0 = self.decoder_block0(y1)
        return x

device = torch.device("cuda:2" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(device)

model = ConvolutionalAutoEncoder().to(device)
# Loss and optimizer
learning_rate = 0.001
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

params = list(model.parameters())
print(len(params))
print(params[0].size())  # conv1's .weight

num_epochs = 30
total_step = len(train_loader)
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for batch_idx, data in enumerate(train_loader):
        inp, targ = data
        inp = inp.to(device)
        targ = targ.to(device)

        output = model(inp)
        loss = criterion(output, targ)

        model.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # print statistics
        running_loss += loss.item()

        if (batch_idx+1) % 10 == 0:
            print ('Epoch [{}/{}], Step [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}' 
                   .format(epoch+1, num_epochs, i+1, total_step, loss.item()))
```

The full error I am getting is:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-28fa0c94d845> in <module>
     13 
     14         model.zero_grad()
---> 15         loss.backward()
     16         optimizer.step()
     17 

~/anaconda3/envs/gautam_new/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
     91                 products. Defaults to ``False``.
     92         """
---> 93         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
     94 
     95     def register_hook(self, hook):

~/anaconda3/envs/gautam_new/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables)
     88     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
     89         tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph,
---> 90         allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
     91 
     92 

RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

Please help. Also, if possible also advice on how I can make my model deeper. I keep getting CUDA  out of memory error.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be great if you could tell me if my proposed solution worked for you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test your model, but considering the error message it makes sense the cause of your problem lies in the return value of your `forward`.

Currently you are returning `x` which is your actual **input** not the **output**:

```
def forward(self, x):
    x1 = self.encoder_block1(x)
    y1 = self.decoder_block1(x1)
    y0 = self.decoder_block0(y1)
    return x
```

So to return the **output** you might want to change the return value form `x` to `y0`:

```
def forward(self, x):
    x1 = self.encoder_block1(x)
    y1 = self.decoder_block1(x1)
    y0 = self.decoder_block0(y1)
    return y0
```

*About the memory: 

Please don't put too many issues in one question. Imagine you have three completely different issues in one question, and there are three people out there where each of them is able to solve one of your issues, you might end up with **no answer** at all. 
Because none of them is able to give you a complete answer addressing all of these issues.
 But if your split your issues into three questions, you might get just three answers, solving all your issues. In many cases it also can improve the question, because one can be more specific to the problem without writing an entire novel in the question.
Of course if your issues are very related you can put them into one question, but this doesn't seem to be the case here.

 I guess there is still a slight chance your `forward` function had some side effects leading to the memory problem (wild guess - not sure at all about this). So if you're lucky it might solve your memory problem too, but if not you definitely should open a new question about it.*